# SQL error on join and group by

Tags: sql-server

What is wrong with the fallowing SQL statement? I'm getting the error describe below. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

The SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    ContentRequests.Title,ContentRequests.ChapterOrArticleTitle,
    ContentRequests.Institution_Id,
    Institutions.Name
FROM 
    [HexDatabaseDev].[dbo].[ContentRequests]
LEFT JOIN
    Institutions ON Institutions.Id = ContentRequests.Institution_Id
GROUP BY 
    ContentRequests.Title
```

The error I'm getting :

> Column 'HexDatabaseDev.dbo.ContentRequests.ChapterOrArticleTitle' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: the error is pretty clear. If you use `GROUP BY`, then every column in the `SELECT` that is not in an aggregation function, needs to be in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Why are you doing a `GROUP BY` if you are not doing any aggregations (`SUM`, `MIN`,etc).  If you want a unique combinations list, just use `SELECT DISTINCT Content....`

Answer (score 0):

Rule of Group By..

> In the select clause,you can ignore only the  columns involving aggregates or  constants,rest of the columns in select should be in Group By

So in your case.

```
group by
ContentRequests.ChapterOrArticleTitle,ContentRequests.ChapterOrArticleTitle
,ContentRequests.Institution_Id
, Institutions.Name
```

Comment: To help explain, if you are grouping by `ContentRequests.Title` but then ask to see `Institutions.Name` in the result set then there "could" be multiple `Institutions.Name` results for each `ContentRequests.Title`, which breaks what you requested - to group by `ContentRequests.Title` in the first place